# Acumatica performance issue

Tags: acumatica

Every morning when I first login the system, it takes about 13 seconds. And I open the stock item list(1000 items in total), it takes about 16 seconds.

Sometimes these happen when I logout for a while and re-login. Is this normal for Acumatica?

Updates:

I'm trying to preload the whole website through Application Initialization in IIS10.0. But when I config the initializationPage in config editor for Acumatica. I find that it's very difficult to set this. Because the url of Acumatica is changing like below, the number after "W" is changing for no reason. Then I can't set a preload url. Anyone can help on this?

```
/AcumaticaERP/(W(5))/Main?....
/AcumaticaERP/(W(7))/Main?....
```

My system info:

- OS: Windows 10
- Processor: Intel i7 4790K 4Ghz
- Memory: 8 GB RAM
- Storage: 120 GB SSD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are experiencing what is called 'idle time-out' and this is normal for IIS depending on configuration.

If you are hosting on-premise you can change these settings in IIS (inetmgr.exe). Select the AppPool used for your Acumatica instance, go into Advanced Settings and location idle time-out options:
[image]

If the Acumatica instance is hosted by another party like a SAAS provider you should contact them about it. Note that this could affect ressource consumptions for a low traffic website and ressource in SAAS plans could mean money.

Comment: Another possibility is that you are getting performance boost by the caching system. Acumatica will cache records when possible to avoid requesting them again from the database. There isn't much you can do about caching, disabling it (if possible?) will give you constant lower performance instead of sporadic performance boost.

Comment: I found the problem is caching system. When I first enter the stock item page for example, Acumatica gathered all records from database and put them into cache. This costed about 16s (1k items). And I think maybe I can make a web crawler visit Acumatica 1 hour a time. Then other user will always get the record from cache. Is this a good idea?

Comment: On the surface it doesn't seem like a good idea because you would be using the system in a way it wasn't intended. Although it could speed things up for this specific scenario. The issue is similar to RAM caching, you could pre-load frequently started programs on RAM drives instead of letting the OS load those from HD. It's unclear whether doing so brings real performance benefits as the OS designer might have better allocated that RAM to another task.

Answer (score 0):

For a preload URL you can simply ignore the `W(...)` part - you won't be able to get there anyway, as it requires authentication. Simply enter the root part (in your case - up to `AcumaticaERP/`).

Comment: You mean I can only preload the root page(login page) with this method?

Comment: You can preload any page that does not require authentication.